# getting the map's value object's class name

Tags: reflection, groovy

I have a param Map which can contain strings as well as custom object types as value. How can I get the class name of the Maps value entry.

```
Right now if I do 
 paramMap.each {
    println(it.value.class.name) 
}
```

It gives me all entries as `java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`
How can I get the actual `type` of the value stored in the map
like String, Configuration, SecurityConfig... etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
paramMap.each { key, value ->
    println( value.getClass().name )
}
```